# What is the meaning of TIME_WAIT state in windows , when i entered NETSTAT -NA in Commend prompt?

Tags: mysql, windows, tcp, cmd

When I entered netstat -na in cmd prompt I get below out put, What is the meaning of TIME_WAIT State.

```
C:\user\hp\>netstat -na
port       Local Address            Foreign Address       State
TCP        192.168.1.556:49152      192.168.1.662:3306    TIME_WAIT
```

Like this I have so many TIME_WAIT.

What is the meaning of TIME_WAIT State ? Is there any problem with TIME_WAIT State ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html):

> The purpose of TIME_WAIT is to keep a connection accepting packets
>   even after the connection has been closed. This is because Internet
>   routing can cause a packet to take a slow route to its destination and
>   it may arrive after both sides have agreed to close. If the port is in
>   use for a new connection, that packet from the old connection could
>   break the protocol or compromise personal information from the
>   original connection. The TIME_WAIT delay prevents this by ensuring
>   that the port cannot be reused until after some time has been
>   permitted for those delayed packets to arrive.

Comment: with this is there any problem ?

Comment: @honey1 No, it is a deliberate design feature of TCP. It only lasts two minutes.

Comment: So there is no problem, the new connection should open , so TIME_WAIT is not effecting on opening new connection.

Comment: So there is no problem, the new connection should open , so TIME_WAIT is not effecting on opening new connection.

Comment: @honey1:- Yes thats true.

Comment: because why i am asking , i am getting time_wait status till value:65534, so it is not effecting on other application, and new connection should open Right. - plz give me reply. @ Rahul Tripathi

Comment: @RahulTripathi No. [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) has nothing to do with TIME_WAIT.

Comment: @EJP:- Yes, got confused. Removed it.